# Kernel attempts to kill MySQL with sigkill

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, kernel

I'm running an Ubuntu server for MySQL.

### Server info

- Ubuntu 12.10
- MySQL installed via `apt`
- RAM: 512M
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` : 300M
- There is no other memory intensive application running on this box.

### Problem

Every morning, at approx. 6:40am something happens to cause a noticeable change in memory:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12520837/mem.s.png

At the same time, a systematic "kill" of running processes seems to occur, causing MySQL to restart.

> Apr 10 06:43:40 mysql-01 kernel: [1866472.511966] select 1 (init), adj 0, size 41, to kill
>
> Apr 10 06:43:40 mysql-01 kernel: [1866472.511973] select 385 (dbus-daemon), adj 0, size 44, to kill
>
> Apr 10 06:43:40 mysql-01 kernel: [1866472.511975] select 389 (rsyslogd), adj 0, size 124, to kill
>
> Apr 10 06:43:40 mysql-01 kernel: [1866472.511982] select 4578 (snmpd), adj 0, size 160, to kill
>
> Apr 10 06:43:40 mysql-01 kernel: [1866472.514157] select 1 (init), adj 0, size 41, to kill
>
> Apr 10 06:43:40 mysql-01 kernel: [1866472.514164] select 385 (dbus-daemon), adj 0, size 
>   44, to kill
>
> Apr 10 06:43:40 mysql-01 kernel: [1866472.514166] select 389 (rsyslogd), adj 0, size 124, to kill
>
> Apr 10 06:43:40 mysql-01 kernel: [1866472.514171] select 4578 (snmpd), adj 0, size 160, to kill
>
> Apr 10 06:43:44 mysql-01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[21807]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
>
> Apr 10 06:43:45 mysql-01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[21810]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
>
> Apr 10 06:43:45 mysql-01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[21810]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
>
> Apr 10 06:43:45 mysql-01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[21810]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
>
> Apr 10 06:43:45 mysql-01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[21810]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.29, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
>
> Apr 10 06:43:45 mysql-01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[21821]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
>   Apr 10 06:43:45 mysql-01 /etc/mysql/debian-start[21826]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables

Any help diagnosing this would be much appreciated!

Comment: 512 MB, seriously?

Comment: Yes, seriously.

Comment: That's a really small amount of memory to run linux on nowadays, let alone a mysql server. As for diagnosing, I'd look into things like log rotation, cron and update scripts for apt..

Comment: Nick with all due respect, unless you know exactly what this database is used for and what the performance requirements are, I can't see why you are commenting about the amount of RAM.

Comment: What uses the database?  A program on another server?  How many connections are allowed at once?

Comment: Fair enough, ignore what I wrote above the part about the cron, log rotation and update scripts/daemons. If it's always at 6:40 am, have a look at /var/log/cron, both on that machine, and on machines that connect, perhaps it's a backup or mysql dump run remotely?

Comment: rob, NickW is commenting on the amount of memory because the OOM killer (Out Of Memory) is what's shooting your MySQL.  If you also don't have any swap configured, then **I'm not at all surprised that your database keeps getting shot in the head**; it wouldn't need anything pathological to happen to cause that, on such a tightly-constrained system.

Comment: Thanks everyone, and apologies to @NickW for dismissing his comment about memory so quick. The cause seems to indeed be SNMPD, I found several bug reports regarding memory leak with this package and after logging its memory usage periodically it appears to steadily grow uncontrollably each day until OOM kicks in (looks like the 6:50 was just coincidence, possibly when the cron.daily scripts run, tipping it over the edge) This service has been removed and an alternative for monitoring is now in use and seems to be running normally.

Comment: Glad you found the cause of your memory munching process!

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 if you don't know how to.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel is detecting that it is running out of memory, possibly because some process is running wild.

Usually [OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) will try to identify this process, and kill it.
The reason it is killing mysql is because this is probably the process that is currently taking the most amount of ram, so it's a very likely candidate for the running wild process.

However, it also seems like snmpd is the culprit. (it is taking 160MB's which is a lot)
snmpd is a deamon responsible for listening for [snmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) traffic, it seems weird for it to take this much memory.

Since this is happening each day at the same time, check your daily [cron jobs](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/).
And check your snmpd log file.
Also check for incomming connections around that time. (from sshd)

All these log files should be showing up somewhere in /var/log/xxx

If this turns up nothing unexpected, look in the log files for the other processes mentioned in the log. (mysql and rsyslogd)

Also, from your graph you only have 66MB free on average, and are running in to memory issues way more then just at 6.40, almost 20% of the time you seem to have less then a few MB's free, never more then 100MB free. (if I correctly see that the magenta bar is the free memory?)